# Universal Key Code (Java)

Tags: java, keyboard

Hi I'm programming a listener that based on the key pressed by the user, must act in a certain manner.

I need to be able to determine if a user press the <kbd>I</kbd> key or <kbd>M</kbd> key. Actually I'm doing it like:

```
// If pressed the 'i' key
if ( evt.getKeyCode() == 73) {
    //
}
...
```

[I look out here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) and with the sample applet determine that the <kbd>I</kbd> key is recognized as a 73 code.

That works.

But I'm working at Mac OS X, and I don't know if once I try to run this app on another OS or just JVM, It won't work.

Is the 73 a universal key code? Is there a certain way to program this so it can run and determine the key pressed, on windows.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just complementing Paul Brinkley's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141400/universal-key-code-java/2141448#2141448).

> Is the 73 a universal key code?

Yes, it is the [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii) code of the upper case letter, 'I' in that case. See the javadoc for [KeyEvent.VK_A](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_A)

### Attention

despite this *coincidence*, it's better not to do something like `getKeyCode() == 'A'` - it may fail in future implementations.

Answer (score 9):

Oh, you're looking for the KeyEvent.VK_Whatever constants.

```
if ( evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_I) {
    // user pressed 'i'
} else if ( evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_M) {
    // user pressed 'm'
}
```

See KeyEvent API docs for the rest.  Should make sense.

Answer (score 2):

As others have suggested, using constants from [`KeyEvent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) is the right way to go. You might enjoy looking at source of this [game](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/); it's a [`KeyEvent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) bonanza. Although Java has excellent cross-platform support, you're smart to test. I've used two major approaches:

- Post open source demos and ask for feedback.
- Run other operating systems in Sun's [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/).