# How can I get a certain point of a rotating image after it has been rotated?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have been working on a top down game for about a day or two and I am trying to figure out how to get a point after I translate and rotate and object back to its original position. I have an image (a weapon) and I rotate it based off of the mouse location and player however, I want to get a certain point of the rotated image after I have rotated it so I can use this point to set the start draw location for bullets, animations, etc. Does anyone know how I can solve this? thanks!!

```
private Point hand, location, handle, barrelExit;
private BufferedImage image;

private double theta;

public WeaponSpriteBase(BufferedImage image, Point location, Point handle, Point barrelExit) {

    super(image, location);

    this.image = image;
    this.location = location;
    this.handle = handle;
    this.barrelExit = barrelExit;

    //Sets the hand location getter
    hand = PlayerSprite.playerHand();

}

public void draw(Graphics2D g2, int currentMouseX, int currentMouseY) {

    theta = PlayerSprite.DegreeFinder(currentMouseX, currentMouseY);

    //Refreshes the hands location getter
    hand = PlayerSprite.playerHand();

    setLocation(hand.x - handle.x, hand.y - handle.y);

    g2.translate(hand.x, hand.y);
    g2.rotate(-Math.toRadians(theta));

    setLocation(-handle.x, - handle.y);

    if(theta > 90 && theta < 270) {
        flipVert(g2);
    }

    else {
        super.draw(g2);
    }

    g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(theta));
    g2.translate(-hand.x, -hand.y);

    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.drawRect(hand.x - 1, hand.y - 1, 2, 2);
    g2.setColor(Color.black);


    //Want to get a certain point on the image and draw it here (with barrelExit.x , barrelExit.y) without rotating it

    
}
```

}

Comment: I fall back to “point on a circle” theory. You know the radius (length of the weapon) it’s rotation point and it’s angle, from there you can calculate the “point on a circle” a projectile should appear, and the angle it should travel

Comment: Two approaches are examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44363464/230513): one uses use the geometry directly, as @MadProgrammer suggests; the other uses the inverse transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know...

- The position of the weapon
- It's angle of direction
- The length (from it's centre point to it's end point)

Then you can simply apply a "point on circle" approach to the problem, for example...

[image]

The blue line is the weapon, the red line is the projection of the projectile path.  Oddly enough, it's calculating both the start and end point the projectile should follow

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    enum WeaponInput {
        LEFT, RIGHT, NONE
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private static final double MIN_WEAPON_ANGLE = -85;
        private static final double MAX_WEAPON_ANGLE = 85;

        private double angleOfWeapon = 0;
        private double weaponAngleDelta = 1;

        private WeaponInput weaponInput = WeaponInput.NONE;

        private Timer timer;

        public TestPane() {
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), "Pressed.weaponMoveLeft");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), "Pressed.weaponMoveRight");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), "Pressed.weaponReleasedLeft");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), "Pressed.weaponReleasedRight");

            WeaponMovementAction.WeaponObserver weaponObserver = new WeaponMovementAction.WeaponObserver() {
                @Override
                public void weaponDidMove(WeaponInput weaponInput) {
                    TestPane.this.weaponInput = weaponInput;
                }
            };

            am.put("Pressed.weaponMoveLeft", new WeaponMovementAction(WeaponInput.LEFT, weaponObserver));
            am.put("Pressed.weaponMoveRight", new WeaponMovementAction(WeaponInput.RIGHT, weaponObserver));
            am.put("Pressed.weaponReleasedLeft", new WeaponMovementAction(WeaponInput.NONE, weaponObserver));
            am.put("Pressed.weaponReleasedRight", new WeaponMovementAction(WeaponInput.NONE, weaponObserver));

            timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    switch (weaponInput) {
                        case LEFT:
                            angleOfWeapon -= weaponAngleDelta;
                            break;
                        case RIGHT:
                            angleOfWeapon += weaponAngleDelta;
                            break;
                    }
                    if (angleOfWeapon < MIN_WEAPON_ANGLE) {
                        angleOfWeapon = MIN_WEAPON_ANGLE;
                    } else if (angleOfWeapon > MAX_WEAPON_ANGLE) {
                        angleOfWeapon = MAX_WEAPON_ANGLE;
                    }

                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        protected Point2D getPointOnCircle(double degress, double radius) {
            double rads = Math.toRadians(degress - 90); // 0 becomes the top

            // Calculate the outter point of the line
            double xPosy = Math.cos(rads) * radius;
            double yPosy = Math.sin(rads) * radius;

            return new Point2D.Double(xPosy, yPosy);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            int centerX = getWidth() / 2;
            int centerY = getHeight() / 2;

            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.drawRect(centerX - 20, centerY - 20, 40, 40);

            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.translate(centerX, centerY - 20);

            // Projection of projectile
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            Point2D endOfWeaponPoint = getPointOnCircle(angleOfWeapon, 20);
            g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(new Point2D.Double(0, 0), endOfWeaponPoint));

            // Weapon direction
            int radius = Math.max(getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            Point2D poc = getPointOnCircle(angleOfWeapon, radius);
            g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(endOfWeaponPoint, poc));

            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class WeaponMovementAction extends AbstractAction {

        public interface WeaponObserver {

            public void weaponDidMove(WeaponInput weaponInput);
        }

        private WeaponInput weaponInput;
        private WeaponObserver observer;

        public WeaponMovementAction(WeaponInput weaponInput, WeaponObserver observer) {
            this.weaponInput = weaponInput;
            this.observer = observer;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            getObserver().weaponDidMove(getWeaponInput());
        }

        public WeaponInput getWeaponInput() {
            return weaponInput;
        }

        public WeaponObserver getObserver() {
            return observer;
        }

    }
}
```